# Share code between two different child classes

Tags: vb.net

In my project I use a 3rd party library (for which I don't have the
source code) that provides ribbon-style forms.

There are two different types of forms actually used in the project, **Office2007Form** and **Office2007RibbonForm**.

This is the hierarchy tree of the provided form classes:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form
 +-RibbonForm
    +-OfficeForm
    |  +-Office2007Form     <---
    +-Office2007RibbonForm  <---
```

In my forms' `form.Designer.vb` I replace `Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form` with either `Inherits Library.Office2007Form` or `Inherits Library.Office2007RibbonForm`.

Now I want to add some default behaviour to my project's forms.

To do this I could create a base form class, insert there my code and then inherit from my base class.
The problem here is that I have two different types of form, **Office2007Form** and **Office2007RibbonForm**, so I should implement my code twice:

```
Public Class MyBaseForm
    Inherits Library.Office2007Form

    Public Property MyProp As String = ""

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New

        Me.Icon = My.Resources.appicon

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

        If e.KeyCode = Keys.F12 Then Suggestions(Me.Text)

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class MyBaseRibbonForm
    Inherits Library.Office2007RibbonForm

    Public Property MyProp As String = ""

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New

        Me.Icon = My.Resources.appicon

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

        If e.KeyCode = Keys.F12 Then Suggestions(Me.Text)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Since vb.net/c# don't support multiple inharitance, I can't find a way to implement this code only once.

Comment: If you have any control over `Library`, then just insert your own base class into the hierarchy with the bits that you want.  If not, I think you're SOL.  You could still write a common `Sub` or `Function` in a module to do the desired processing, but you'll have to write the code to call it manually.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking and the inheritance chain.  you would put the common code in the RibbonForm class (or something else at the same level) then with the correct access modifiers it will be available to the inherited forms

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have library source code